# How to select the value of a key from objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, dom

I want to change the innerHTML of 3 elements to display whats inside of `questionText`, `options`, and `answer`.

So for example, `element1.innerHTML = (what ever is inside of questionText)`

```
const questions = [
  {
    questionText: "Commonly used data types DO NOT include:",
    options: ["1. strings", "2. booleans", "3. alerts", "4. numbers"],
    answer: "3. alerts"
  }]
```

Comment: Did you mean `element1.innerHTML = questions[0].questionText;` ?

Comment: `element1.innerHTML = questions[0].questionText;` `element2.innerHTML = questions[0].options;` and `element3.innerHTML = questions[0].answer;`

Comment: Since `options` is an array, you might want to turn it into a `<select>` with each element being an `<option>`.

Answer (score 0):

Some small example how to fill dom elements from js

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="q"></div>
     <div><select id="op"></select></div>
     <div id="an"></div>
     <script>
       const element1 = document.getElementById('q');
       const element2 = document.getElementById('op');
       const element3 = document.getElementById('an');
       const questions = [
        {
          questionText: "Commonly used data types DO NOT include:",
          options: ["1. strings", "2. booleans", "3. alerts", "4. numbers"],
          answer: "3. alerts",

      }];
     element1.innerHTML = questions[0].questionText;
     for (const op of questions[0].options) {
       const option = document.createElement("option");
       option.text =  op;
       element2.add(option);
     }
    element3.innerHTML = questions[0].answer;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```